# The SqlParameter is already contained in another SqlParameterCollection

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

Below is my whole class named *DataAccessLayer*

- the problem is when I add more than 1 parameter they have the same name
  even though i did add them in my arraylist named *paramlist* with uniquely different names
- because of that I'm receiving **"The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection"** error when i call my *setParameter* sub
- I do clear parameters in my *paramlist* and *cmd* before I add a new set of parameters

```js
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class DataAccessLayer
    Public cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim param As New SqlParameter
    Dim paramlist As New ArrayList
    Public Sub connectToDB()
        cmd = New SqlCommand
        conn = New SqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=10.10.30.104\CGHMSSQL;Initial Catalog=dbPractice;User ID=sa;Password=12345"
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    End Sub
    Public Function getDataTable(ByVal storedProc As String) As DataTable
        connectToDB()
        da = New SqlDataAdapter
        dt = New DataTable
        cmd.CommandText = storedProc
        dt.Clear()
        setParameter(cmd)
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)
        Return dt
    End Function
    Public Sub executeQuery(ByVal storedProc As String)
        connectToDB()
        cmd.CommandText = storedProc
        setParameter(cmd)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Sub
    Public Sub setParameter(ByVal cmd As SqlCommand)
        For Each param As SqlParameter In paramlist
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param)
        Next
    End Sub
    Public Sub addParameter(ByVal parameterName As String, ByVal dbType As DbType, ByVal value As Object)
        param.ParameterName = parameterName
        param.DbType = dbType
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        param.Value = If((value Is Nothing), DBNull.Value, value)
        paramlist.Add(param)
    End Sub
    Public Sub clearParameters()
        paramlist.Clear()
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: 1) You appear to have forgotten to .Dispose() of the SQL command and the SQL connection after the query. 2) Your DataAccessLayer class should implement a .Dispose method of its own to make sure the SQL command and SQL connection have .Dispose() called on them if they are not Nothing. 3) You should use a `List(Of SqlParameter)` rather than the out-dated ArrayList. 4) You only need to create a New DataTable when the `getDataTable` function is called. 5) You should not use the "sa" account for general purposes.

Comment: very much appreciated

Comment: The first line in `addParameter` should be `param = New SqlParameter`, otherwise you are using the same one repeatedly. Actually, you should probably take out the `New` for most of the variables you declare at the start of the class, and only make New ones just before they are needed.

Comment: very much appreciated